# Java partial parse of XML file and attributes

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I need to parse an xml file where I don't know the whole structure but I know a few Nodes and attributes that I wish to parse, lets say I have this file structure:

```
<Root>
//lots and lots of irrelevant info here
               <Name>
                    <EffectiveName Value="My-Name" />
                    <UserName Value="" />
                    <Annotation Value="" />
                    <MemorizedFirstClipName Value="" />
                </Name>
//lots and lots of irrelevant info here
<NotNeeded1>
    <NotNeeded2>
       //more nodes
          <NotNeeded13>
               <KeyTracks>
                                                <KeyTrack Id="43">
                                                    <Notes>
                                                        <MidiNoteEvent Time="0" Duration="0.5" Velocity="120" VelocityDeviation="0" OffVelocity="64" Probability="1" IsEnabled="true" NoteId="73" />
                                                    </Notes>
                                                    <MidiKey Value="0" />
                                                </KeyTrack>
                                                <KeyTrack Id="44">
                                                    <Notes>
                                                        <MidiNoteEvent Time="0.5" Duration="0.5" Velocity="120" VelocityDeviation="0" OffVelocity="64" Probability="1" IsEnabled="true" NoteId="75" />
                                                    </Notes>
                                                    <MidiKey Value="1" />
                                                </KeyTrack>
                                                <KeyTrack Id="45">
                                                    <Notes>
                                                        <MidiNoteEvent Time="1" Duration="0.5" Velocity="120" VelocityDeviation="0" OffVelocity="64" Probability="1" IsEnabled="true" NoteId="77" />
                                                    </Notes>
                                                    <MidiKey Value="2" />
                                                </KeyTrack>
                                                <KeyTrack Id="46">
                                                    <Notes>
                                                        <MidiNoteEvent Time="1.5" Duration="0.5" Velocity="120" VelocityDeviation="0" OffVelocity="64" Probability="1" IsEnabled="true" NoteId="79" />
                                                    </Notes>
                                                    <MidiKey Value="3" />
                                                </KeyTrack>
                                            </KeyTracks>
             </NotNeeded13>  
         //more nodes
      </NotNeeded2>
 </NotNeeded1>
//lots and lots of irrelevant info here
</Root>
```

It is far bigger then that but just for the sake of the example.

I wish to extract and parse the file to the following objects:

CustomObject.class

```
public class CustomObject{
   private String effectiveName;
   private List<KeyTrack> keyTracks;
}
```

KeyTracks.class

```
public class KeyTrack {
    private Integer keyTrackId;
    private MidiNoteEvent midiNoteEvent;
    private Integer midiKey;
}
```

MidiNoteEvent .class

```
public class MidiNoteEvent {
    private Double time;
    private Integer velocity;
    private Double duration;
    private Boolean isEnabled;
}
```

I am trying to do it as generic as I can so I won't have to change my parser if I need to add another node or attribute, so switch/case or if/else is not right for my case there can be hundreds of nodes and additions and I don't want to have to change multiple classes if need to parse extra info.

I tried to create an enum for the nodes I need, but I can't find the sweet spot to be able to grab the nodes correctly.

These are my parsers' function for now

```
private final Map<String, Object> map;

 @Override
    public ProjectTrack parse(Node node) {
        parseToMap(node);
        return mapper.convertValue(map, CustomObject.class);
    }

    private void parseToMap(Node node){
        if(Arrays.stream(RelevantMidiTrackNodes.values()).anyMatch(
                e -> e.getNodeName().equals(node.getNodeName()))
        ){
            System.out.print(node.getNodeName()  + ": ");
            for (int i = 0; i < node.getAttributes().getLength(); i++) {
                Attr attribute = (Attr)node.getAttributes().item(i);
                System.out.print(attribute.getNodeName()  + " - " + attribute.getValue() + ", ");
                map.put(attribute.getNodeName(), attribute.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                //calls this method for all the children which is Element
                parseToMap(currentNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

Updated the the file itself, the nodes I need can be 10 nodes deeper and the parents are irrelevant so I am looking for a way to extract nodes in the 1st,2nd levels and also 10th level.

In my example to extract EffectiveName to a string and KeyTracks to a list

Comment: It could be better to get the needed elements with XPath and then unmarshall them. Besides, the question should provide a [mcve] including the minimum complete xml structure.

Comment: I uploaded the structure of the xml that I need and the objects that I need it to be parsed to. Not sure exactly what is missing if you can elaborate, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's is an example of how to get nodes with xpath and unmarshall them to pojos. Using XPath avoids creating the whole object structure needed to directly unmarshall `KeyTrack` object since a class representing each Element would be needed (Notes and MidiKey).

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        FileInputStream fileIS;
        fileIS = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/tmp/tmp.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( KeyTrack.class, MidiNoteEvent.class );
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        Document xmlDocument;
        xmlDocument = builder.parse(fileIS);

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73913800/java-partial-parse-of-xml-file-and-attributes/73914420#73914420
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression ktxp = xPath.compile("//KeyTrack");
        XPathExpression mnexp = xPath.compile("./Notes/MidiNoteEvent");
        XPathExpression mkxp = xPath.compile("./MidiKey");

        NodeList trackList =(NodeList) ktxp.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < trackList.getLength(); i++) {
            KeyTrack kt = (KeyTrack) u.unmarshal(trackList.item(i));
            
        NodeList nodeList =(NodeList) mnexp.evaluate(trackList.item(i), XPathConstants.NODESET);
        MidiNoteEvent o = (MidiNoteEvent) u.unmarshal( nodeList.item(0) );
        kt.setMidiNoteEvent(o);
            
            Element valAttr =(Element) mkxp.evaluate(trackList.item(i), XPathConstants.NODE);
            kt.setMidiKey(Integer.parseInt(valAttr.getAttribute("Value") ));
            
            System.out.println(kt);
        }
        
}
```

**MidiNoteEvent.java** with proper annotations

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="MidiNoteEvent")
public class MidiNoteEvent {
    
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Time")
    private Double time;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Velocity")
    private Integer velocity;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Duration")
    private Double duration;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "IsEnabled")
    private Boolean isEnabled;
    // getters/setters // toString generated by Eclipse
}
```

With **KeyTrack.java** as below

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="KeyTrack")
public class KeyTrack {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Id")
    private Integer keyTrackId;
    
    @XmlElement(name="MidiNoteEvent")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="Notes")
    private List<MidiNoteEvent> midiNoteEvent;
    
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Value")
    private Integer midiKey;

    // getters/setters
}
```

`for-loop` would be

```
        for (int i = 0; i < trackList.getLength(); i++) {
            KeyTrack kt = (KeyTrack) u.unmarshal(trackList.item(i));
            
            Element valAttr =(Element) mkxp.evaluate(trackList.item(i), XPathConstants.NODE);
            kt.setMidiKey(Integer.parseInt(valAttr.getAttribute("Value") ));
            
            System.out.println(kt);
        }
```

Result

```
KeyTrack [keyTrackId=43, midiNoteEvent=[MidiNoteEvent [time=0.0, velocity=120, duration=0.5, isEnabled=true]], midiKey=0]
KeyTrack [keyTrackId=44, midiNoteEvent=[MidiNoteEvent [time=0.5, velocity=120, duration=0.5, isEnabled=true]], midiKey=1]
KeyTrack [keyTrackId=45, midiNoteEvent=[MidiNoteEvent [time=1.0, velocity=120, duration=0.5, isEnabled=true]], midiKey=2]
KeyTrack [keyTrackId=46, midiNoteEvent=[MidiNoteEvent [time=1.5, velocity=120, duration=0.5, isEnabled=true]], midiKey=3]
```

Comment: The schema is clearly expected to change over time, and in my view data binding (JAXB) is always a poor approach when schema changes are frequent.

Comment: Xpath are relative so schema changes are not significant in this case.

Comment: The typical issue is that schema changes can invalidate existing Java code so you immediately have a change control problem implementing schema changes, because you don't know what their impact is without rebuilding and retesting.

Comment: Given that case, why a xslt approach wouldn't be invalidadted if schema changes?

Comment: XSLT's processing model based on match patterns is all designed to make the code as robust as possible against schema changes; and (in general) processors don't access a schema at compile time; they are purely interpreted.

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't able to extract the custom object with your approach. Please note that the node KeyTracks is about 10 nodes deeper so i want to extract it with the name, I will update my file in the question to be more close to reality

Comment: @GiladDahan updated the answer with the complete idea I was suggesting.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am going to do a hybrid solution with yours and @MichaelKay's soluition. I will flatten the original xml I have to decrease it to the relevant nodes and then I will either parse it to classes or send it as a map to the frontend because I am not sure that I need to preserve the data in my server

Answer (score 1):

My personal tool of choice for pretty well all XML processing is XSLT. When you mix XSLT and Java the details vary from one XSLT processor to another, but this is how to do it using XSLT 3.0 and Saxon. This example uses the open source version.

First, write a stylesheet that extracts the data you want as an XDM (XPath Data Model) map:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:map>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="//EffectiveName, //KeyTrack"/>
  </xsl:map>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//EffectiveName">
  <xsl:map-item key="'EffectiveName'" select="@Value"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//KeyTrack">
  <xsl:map-item key="@Id" select="map{
      "time":      number(Nodes/@Time),
      "velocity":  number(Notes/@Velocity),
      "duration":  number(Notes/@Duration),
      "isEnabled": string(Notes/@IsEnabled),
      "midiKey":   number(MidiKey/@Value),
     }"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Run this transformation to deliver a Saxon XdmMap object:

```
Processor proc = new Processor(false);
DocumentBuilder builder = proc.newDocumentBuilder();
XdmNode source = builder.build("input.xml");
XsltCompiler comp = proc.newXsltCompiler();
Xslt30Transformer trans = comp.compile("stylesheet.xsl").load30();
XdmMap result = (XdmMap)trans.applyTemplates(source);
```

Then process the XdmMap to construct the Java POJOs you want to use in your application.

```
for (Map.Entry<> entry : result.entrySet()) {
   String key = entry.getKey().getStringValue();
   if (key.equals("EffectiveName") {
     ...
   } else {
      ...
   }
}
```

If you prefer, with very little change you could make the stylesheet output the data you want in JSON, and then use a JSON library to build your POJOs.

Actually, if I were doing it, I would ask whether you actually need to process the data in Java at all - I would probably try and find a way to do the whole job in XSLT. But I don't know what the "whole job" is, so that may be unrealistic.

Comment: Thanks for that, I am not familiar with this approach so I will look into it. The file itself is large and there are a lot of nodes that I don't need, most of the nodes I need are inner nodes like 9-10 nodes deep and the parents are irrelevant. Also I wanted to have like an enum or something that could help building the file, without the need to change in 2 places. In your case if I need extra node I need to change stylesheet.xsl and the if\else when parsing to POJO

Comment: I updated the file and description a bit hope it will be clearer

Comment: I read about it a little bit it is a very nit solution. Follow up question, can I even avoid changing\adding\removing nodes from 2 different places?